# How can I know that a Trigger is fired or not?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 on a windows 7 machine. I have a trigger that should be fired on an insert but unfortunately it does not. I do not have the SQL Profiler because I have an express edition. Is there any other way to see what is going wrong?. The insert into the table teams is done with the Import Wizard of SQL Server, an i import from .CSV into a table.

```
CREATE TRIGGER teams.process ON teams
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @homeTeamId INT
    DECLARE @awayTeamId INT
    DECLARE @maxTeamId INT
    DECLARE @matchId INT

    SELECT @maxTeamId = 0
    SELECT @maxTeamId = ISNULL(MAX(teamId), 0) from tblTeams

    --- Check if home team has already been inserted into the table.
    SELECT @homeTeamId = -1
    SELECT 
        @homeTeamId = teamId 
    FROM 
        tblTeams t
        JOIN inserted i
        ON t.teamName = i.hometeam
    IF (@homeTeamId = -1) 
    BEGIN
        SELECT @homeTeamId = @maxTeamId + 1
        SELECT @maxTeamId = @maxTeamId + 1
        INSERT INTO tblTeams SELECT @homeTeamId, i.hometeam FROM inserted i
    END

    --- Check if away team has already been inserted into the table.
    SELECT @awayTeamId = -1
    SELECT 
        @awayTeamId = teamId 
    FROM 
        tblTeams t
        JOIN inserted i
        ON t.teamName = i.awayteam
    IF (@awayTeamId = -1) 
    BEGIN
        SELECT @awayTeamId = @maxTeamId + 1
        SELECT @maxTeamId = @maxTeamId + 1
        INSERT INTO tblTeams SELECT @awayTeamId, i.awayteam FROM inserted i
    END

    -- insert a record into the matches table with the home team ID and away team ID.
    SELECT @matchId = 0
    SELECT @matchId = ISNULL(MAX(MatchId), 0) FROM tblMatches
    INSERT INTO tblMatches 
    SELECT @matchId + 1, @homeTeamId, @awayTeamId, i.score 
    FROM inserted i
END
```

Comment: If you have defined a trigger on insert and it is not disabled then it will be being executed on insert. You can check in `sys.triggers` for disabled triggers.

Comment: Free Sql Server Express profiler can be found [here](https://sites.google.com/site/sqlprofiler/).

Comment: It the trigger produces an error or something , how can i see the error ?

Comment: Error would be reported to client that issued `insert` statement. You might add print statements to trigger body and execute insert in SSMS to see if trigger is being executed; if it does, there is probably a misjoin or some other error that produces zero rows in one of the queries in trigger. Could you please post the trigger?

Comment: Is it possible that the trigger is firing, but not doing what you expected it to do? A frequent cause of this is when people write triggers that assume `inserted` only contains a single row, then find it "hasn't worked" when a multi-row insert is executed.

Comment: Hm, how can i put print statements?. And where can i see them ?

Comment: Well, I can confirm that your trigger *is* broken for multi-row inserts. Why are you managing the IDs in these tables manually rather than using (say) `IDENTITY` columns?

Comment: [Here is documentation on print statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176047.aspx). But you need a few fixes: start the trigger with [set nocount on](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189837%28v=sql.105%29.aspx); add [identity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) primary key to `tblTeams` and `tblMatches` and drop `select isnull(max(` method because it will produce duplicate id's in multiuser environment; and rewrite inserts to tblTeams to insert ALL non-matching teams in one go - this means `do not use local variables`.

Answer (score 1):

Okay. If we can change the table definitions of `tblTeams` and `tblMatches` slightly, so that they maintain their own `ID` columns using `IDENTITY`, then we can fix the trigger to be safe for multi-row inserts:

```
create table teams (
    hometeam varchar(10) not null,
    awayteam varchar(10) not null,
    score int not null
)
create table tblteams (
    teamId int IDENTITY(1,1) not null,
    teamName varchar(10) not null
)
create table tblmatches (
    matchId int IDENTITY(1,1) not null,
    HomeTeamID int not null,
    AwayTeamID int not null,
    Score int not null
)
go
CREATE TRIGGER process ON teams
AFTER INSERT
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON
declare @TeamIDs table (TeamID int not null,TeamName varchar(10) not null)

;with AllTeams as (
    select hometeam as teamName from inserted
    union
    select awayteam from inserted
)
merge into tblTeams tt using AllTeams at on tt.teamName = at.teamName
when matched then update set teamName = at.teamName
when not matched then insert (teamName) values (at.teamName)
output inserted.TeamID,inserted.teamName into @TeamIDs;

insert into tblmatches (HomeTeamID,AwayTeamID,Score)
select ht.TeamID,at.TeamID,i.Score
from inserted i
inner join @TeamIDs ht on i.hometeam = ht.TeamName
inner join @TeamIDs at on i.awayteam = at.TeamName
GO
```

And then we test it out:

```
insert into teams (hometeam,awayteam,score) values
('abc','def',10),
('def','ghi',5),
('jkl','mno',7)
go
insert into teams (hometeam,awayteam,score) values
('abc','ghi',19),
('pqr','stu',11)
go
select * from tblteams
select * from tblmatches
```

The issue with your existing trigger is it didn't cope with `inserted` containing multiple rows - the trigger is fired once per *statement*, not once per *row*. So e.g. these line are wrong:

```
SELECT @homeTeamId = @maxTeamId + 1
    SELECT @maxTeamId = @maxTeamId + 1
    INSERT INTO tblTeams SELECT @homeTeamId, i.hometeam FROM inserted i
```

Since there might be multiple `homeTeam` values to deal with.

It also didn't deal well with concurrency - two calls to the trigger happening in parallel might end up with the *same* `@maxTeamId` value - and then attempt to insert rows into `tblTeam` with the same `TeamId` values - whereas using `IDENTITY` columns, SQL Server deals with this for us automatically.

The only slight fudge in the above is using `MERGE` to insert new teams - the `WHEN MATCHED` line will do a No-Op `UPDATE` for existing rows (since we know the `teamName` matches on both sides), but it's a nice trick to do the lookup of existing rows and `INSERT` of new rows in a single statement.

---

I've just realised that you've said that you're using the Import data wizard. I have a feeling that the SSIS Package that it generates creates a destination using [Fast Load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141237.aspx), and doesn't specify `FIRE_TRIGGERS`. That could scupper you also.

You could either generate the package using the wizard, then edit the properties, or use the wizard to insert into a staging table, then do a plain `INSERT`/`SELECT` from that table into our `teams` table, and let the trigger fire that way.

Answer (score 1):

Bulk insert wizards / data import wizards usually bypass triggers on the destination table.